# long to wide in r with all data and unique observation labels in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 columns (Animal, Var1, Var2) and 3 rows (**1 each** for mouse, cat and dog):

```
Animal   Var1  Var2
Mouse    5     5.5
Cat      7     7.4
Dog      1     6.3
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Mouse.Var1 Mouse.Var2 Cat.Var1 Cat.Var2 Dog.Var1 Dog.Var2
5           5.5        7        7.4       1       6.3
```

I have been trying to use reshape and reshape2 but neither seem to work.
Please help.

Comment: "neither seem to work"... what exactly have you tried? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: dcast(df, c("Var1","Var2"), value="Animall"). Yes, I have been reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can in fact be done with the `reshape2` package (though I'm not sure why you would want to). First you have to melt the data so that the Var1 and Var2 columns become labels in a condensed column

```
library(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(Animal = c('Mouse', 'Cat', 'Dog'), Var1 = c(5, 7, 1), Var2 = c(5.5, 7.4, 6.3))
df.melt <- melt(df, id.vars = 'Animal')
```

This produces:

```
  Animal variable value
1  Mouse     Var1   5.0
2    Cat     Var1   7.0
3    Dog     Var1   1.0
4  Mouse     Var2   5.5
5    Cat     Var2   7.4
6    Dog     Var2   6.3
```

This can then be cast to the format you're after:

```
df.wide <- dcast(df.melt, . ~ Animal + variable)

  . Cat_Var1 Cat_Var2 Dog_Var1 Dog_Var2 Mouse_Var1 Mouse_Var2
1 .        7      7.4        1      6.3          5        5.5
```

Comment: Other than the weird dot that appears, its great.

Comment: The dot appears because you need something on the lefthand side of the `dcast` formula. You could also include a name in quotes, such as "value", which isn't necessarily prettier but may make more sense.